# bit, nibbles and shifting in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to understand the bit operations, but after few hours of analysing - still nothing.

Here is the code: https://github.com/merbanan/rtl_433/blob/master/src/rtl_433.c

but the most interesting part is here:

```
static int prologue_callback(uint8_t bb[BITBUF_ROWS][BITBUF_COLS]) {
    int rid;

    int16_t temp2;

    /* FIXME validate the received message better */
    if (((bb[1][0]&0xF0) == 0x90 && (bb[2][0]&0xF0) == 0x90 && (bb[3][0]&0xF0) == 0x90 && (bb[4][0]&0xF0) == 0x90 &&
        (bb[5][0]&0xF0) == 0x90 && (bb[6][0]&0xF0) == 0x90) ||
        ((bb[1][0]&0xF0) == 0x50 && (bb[2][0]&0xF0) == 0x50 && (bb[3][0]&0xF0) == 0x50 && (bb[4][0]&0xF0) == 0x50)) {

        /* Prologue sensor */
        temp2 = (int16_t)((uint16_t)(bb[1][2] << 8) | (bb[1][3]&0xF0));
        temp2 = temp2 >> 4;
        fprintf(stderr, "Sensor temperature event:\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "protocol      = Prologue\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "button        = %d\n",bb[1][1]&0x04?1:0);
        fprintf(stderr, "battery       = %s\n",bb[1][1]&0x08?"Ok":"Low");
        fprintf(stderr, "temp          = %s%d.%d\n",temp2<0?"-":"",abs((int16_t)temp2/10),abs((int16_t)temp2%10));
        fprintf(stderr, "humidity      = %d\n", ((bb[1][3]&0x0F)<<4)|(bb[1][4]>>4));
        fprintf(stderr, "channel       = %d\n",(bb[1][1]&0x03)+1);
        fprintf(stderr, "id            = %d\n",(bb[1][0]&0xF0)>>4);
        rid = ((bb[1][0]&0x0F)<<4)|(bb[1][1]&0xF0)>>4;
        fprintf(stderr, "rid           = %d\n", rid);
        fprintf(stderr, "hrid          = %02x\n", rid);

        fprintf(stderr, "%02x %02x %02x %02x %02x\n",bb[1][0],bb[1][1],bb[1][2],bb[1][3],bb[1][4]);

        if (debug_output)
            debug_callback(bb);

        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
```

I don't understand what is bb[BITBUF_ROWS][BITBUF_COLS].

The algorithm gets the 9 nibbles, which are decoded into some variables, eg. temp, humidity etc.

The example taken from  http://goughlui.com/2013/12/20/rtl-sdr-433-92mhz-askook-decoding-of-various-devices-with-rtl_433/

The input: `10010110 01000100 00010000 00010010 10111000`

The result:

```
button: 1
battery: Low
temp: 25.7
humidity: 43
channel:1 
id: 9
rid :100
hrid: 64
```

Because I don't know if the input is negative or LSB reversed I prepared the table with all situations:

```
bin   dec   neg    neg  rev   rev   neg     neg
            bin    dec        dec   rev     rev dec
1001    9   0110    6   1001    9   0110    6
0110    6   1001    9   0110    6   1001    9
0100    4   1011    11  0010    2   1101    13
0100    4   1011    11  0010    2   1101    13
0001    1   1110    14  1000    8   0111    7
0000    0   1111    15  0000    0   1111    15
0001    1   1110    14  1000    8   0111    7
0010    2   1101    13  0100    4   1011    11
1011    11  0100    4   1101    13  0010    2
1000    8   0111    7   0001    1   1110    14
```

But I definetely don't understand how the temp is 25.7, while there's no 5 at all. the humidity id 43 but there's no 3 value.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `bb[BITBUF_ROWS][BITBUF_COLS]` means that the function receives a 2-dimensional array as the argument. It has `BITBUF_ROWS` rows, and each row has `BITBUF_COLS` columns.

Comment: yes, but what is the item of array - the bit or the byte?

Comment: The elements are `uint8_t`, unsigned 8-bit bytes.

Comment: But the highest index of BITBUF_ROWS is 6, and the highest index of BITBUF_COLS is 3 so, 7x4=28 bytes is much more than 10 bytes of input

Comment: A lot of the higher nibbles seem to be reserved (`0x50` or `0x90`) -- see the first `if` line. Counting by eye, I think 8 nibbles contain all this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All values are in there. The input in hex is

```
96 44 10 12 B8
```

and writing it as nibbles, we get

```
A a | B b | C c | D d | E e
9 6 | 4 4 | 1 0 | 1 2 | B 8
```

With this notation, we can replace `bb[1][0]` with `Aa`, `bb[1][1]` with `Bb` and so forth. I will refer to individual *nibbles* as `A`, `a`, and so on, without the bit shifting and masking, which may make things a bit clearer. To get `A`,`B`, etc. take the byte, mask the 4 highest bits (`& 0xF0)` and shift it right 4 bits (`>>4`). To get `a`,`b`, etc. mask the lowest 4 bits of the original byte: `& 0x0F`.

*Button* is a simple bit flag: bit 2 of `b`: `0100`, so it is **1**. (Bits count right to left and start at 0.)

*Battery* is also a simple bit flag: bit 3 of `b`, so it is `0`, which indicates **"Low"**.

*Temperature* is `((Cc<<8)|D)>>4`: `10<<8 = 1000 + 10 = 1010 >> 4`, or `101` in hex, 257 in decimal. This appears to be in tenths of degrees, hence the division by 10: **25.7** (all that extra manipulation is to display a negative value correctly).

*Humidity* is `(d<<4) | E`, or `20 | B = 2B`, which is **43**.

*Channel* is bits 0-1 of `b` (`00`) plus 1, which equals **1**.

*Id* is the value in `A`: **9**.

*RID*, finally, is `(a<<4) | B`: `60 | 4 = 64`, **100** in decimals. *hrid* is the same value but written in hex.

Comment: Thank you very much, for the clear explanation. Now all is clear - I was fixed, that temp should be BCD format and can't get out of this fixation. After few hours everything mixed and I even was not sure if bb[i][j] is nibble, byte or bit ;D

Answer (score 2):

The temperature bytes are `bb[1][2]` and `bb[1][3]` = `00010000` and `00010010`.

The code appends these, and then shifts right by 4: `0001 0000 0001`

Converting from binary to decimal, this is `257` (hex is `0x101`).

The code divides by ten to get the temperature: 25.7.

Answer (score 1):

The data is packed into the array. For example humidity is extracted from the 4 l.s. bits of `bb[1][3]` and the 4 m.s. bits of `bb[1][4]`.

```
fprintf(stderr, "humidity      = %d\n", ((bb[1][3]&0x0F)<<4)|(bb[1][4]>>4));
```

So if bb[1][3] = xxxx0010 and bb[1][4] = 1011xxxx, humidity = 00101011 = 43

Temperature is similar but more complicated.